Foreign key is not correct after flywaydb migration in postgress and springboot
I have 4 tenants - tenant1,tenant2,tenant3,tenant4,tenant5
and i am using spring boot, postgress database and flywaydb Migration to database version and auto create when new tenant registered.
Base code : https://github.com/AnarSultanov/examples/tree/master/schema-based-multi-tenancy
https://sultanov.dev/blog/schema-based-multi-tenancy-with-spring-data/
in my sql scripts i have added foreign key but after flyway db initializes and app runs
all foreign key for each schema/table are referring to all schema
one schema can access another foreign key table reference


Foreign keys are creating number of tenant present

this ll generate the schema  by looping from the user/tenant table
after fly migrate run successfully , foreign keys are creating multiple times (same count as schema present).
Correct behavior should create only one foriegn key per schema.
sample code to reproduce the issue
https://github.com/jeebendu/schema-based-multi-tenancy
clone and connect to any postgress db , it ll automatic create the 5 tenants
Correct behavior should be only one foreign key

Tenant_1 added Author_t1
While inserting record in Tenant_3 its refering to tenant1 foriegn key data


Can any one help to this ?

Details that can be adequately expressed as formatted text should be posted as such, not as images or links to images. Please edit the post by replacing the images with inline, formatted text.

You could try making all references to tables have the schema in the reference. Flyway allows you to specify a placeholder to help with multi-tenant schemas: https://www.red-gate.com/blog/handling-multiple-schemas-in-the-same-database-with-flyway
CREATE TABLE ${flyway:defaultSchema}.MyTable (id INT);

Other than that - it isn't clear what the exact issue is - could you recreate it in a small reproduction that you can share?
I've downloaded the code, and added in the FK from author to users.
I believe there is an issue in the SQL Query used to examine the FK's - the join to ccu didn't include a condition that the schema's matched and therefore there were extra rows.
This query seems to show that there are the right number of FK's - one per tenant back to the users table:
select tc.table_schema,
       tc.constraint_type,
       tc.constraint_name,
       tc.table_name,
       kcu.column_name,
       ccu.table_schema AS foreign_table_schema,
       ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
       ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name
FROM information_schema.table_constraints as tc
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage as kcu
    on tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
    AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage as ccu
   ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name AND ccu.table_schema = tc.table_schema
WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
--AND tc.table_schema = 'tenant1'
and tc.table_name = 'note';



Hi @Piers
i have committed the small reproduction code to github
link : https://github.com/jeebendu/schema-based-multi-tenancy
in Flyway.config file there is one method which ll create the schema which are present in user table
And after migration of sql queries foriegn keys are shown as multiple in db

Thanks - Is it intended that author map 1-1 to users?

Yes it was one to one map to users

I think you would want to put a foreign key in author to users. You'll need to explicitly provide the schema name for users: default.users to get all the tenant author tables to link to the default.users table.

But issue was with note table foreign key to author
so there its creating multiple foreign key
default user table was only one time add
for that user one schema ll be created and in that schema there ll be 50 table are there with foreign key relationship

i have attached the screenshot for correct behavior, can you refer to above

I've edited my original answer to include the extra information I've found since downloading the code.

But while any inserting foriegn key data in diff tenant table its referring to first tenant
added screenshot

its not about the query , while real data inserting having the issue

I'm not sure I understand the problem you are having. With these changes made https://github.com/jeebendu/schema-based-multi-tenancy/pull/1/files I'm able to insert into individual tenant#.author tables. There is no check that you don't select a user from a different schema though.

This also wrong author.id is not same as user.id
the issue was in note table which contains foreign keys to all schema

there is no issue in hibernate or flyway migration
its issues on postgress

the reproducible code was located at :
https://github.com/piers-williams/schema-based-multi-tenancy/blob/piers-branch/src/main/resources/db/postgress_fk_issue.sql

Its not an issue in Flywaydb or Postgress
Its a issue on heidiSQL Client
Raised request @
https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL/issues/1956
